# Regression with linear transformed matrix

Tags: regression

Intuitively (formal explanation is also welcomed), what would happen if we use a linear transformed matrix in regression?
$\mathbf{XZ}$ instead of $\mathbf{X}$ in $Y = \mathbf{X}\beta +\varepsilon$. I think we can still get consistent estimators, but no more unbiased?

Comment: Suppose $Z$ is of full rank, so that you can find a $\gamma$ for which $Z\gamma=\beta$.  What is the difference between the models $Y=X\beta+\varepsilon$ and $y=XZ\gamma + \varepsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix is created randomly, then you can still expect estimators of the same accuracy. This property is used in popular methods such as random projections. Random projections are used to do dimensionality reduction, with very little actual cost.